# Unit testing in PyCharm

Tags: python, unit-testing, pycharm

Alright, so I am doing Python Crash Course exercies for unit tests chapter and I can't quite get it to work using PyCharm.

My "project" literally consists of two trivial files:

city_functions.py:

```
def city_country(city, country):
    result = '{0}, {1}'.format(city.title(), country.title())
    return result
```

test_cities.py:

```
import unittest
from city_functions import city_country


class CityTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    """Tests for 'city_functions.city_country' function."""

    def test_city_country(self):
        result = city_country('london', 'england')
        self.assertEqual(result, 'London, England')

unittest.main()
```

Now, when I am trying to run the module from PyCharm I get:

```
(...)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

OK
```

but it works, when I run it from command line:

```
> python -m test_cities
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

OK
```

Are there any shenanigans with PyCharm configuration to get it to work? I've read some posts about naming conventions (that test function and the whole module MUST start with 'test', but it already does in my case).

Comment: Yes, there definitely is some set up you need to do when trying to run unittests. It's hard to give step by step instructions. Read the [help](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/run-debug-configuration-unittests.html) carefully and look at the configuration menu to see what options are available to you. Look at *where* you are running your `python -m test_cities` command to understand the relative paths being used to allow this to work.

Comment: Ultimately, in your config you need to determine what the "working" directory is which is where the main execution of the app will be, which in turn is the reference from where your imports are.

Answer (score 2):

Actually adding the main check solved the problem (it works from PyCharm and Command Line):

```
(...)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: @Jedi I don't understand why PyCharm needed the main check though

Comment: If I understand correctly -m argument assures that the module will be run as __main__ module. So from terminal I could run this module like "python test_cities.py" and it worked just fine. For PyCharm to "click" I needed to remove "unittest.main()" line, but then terminal stopped working. That's why I just added main check - I don't know why this line was affecting PyCharm behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem with PyCharm. I am following the Python Crash Course and followed the instructions step by step in chapter 11. And I also had to use:

```
if__name__ == '__main__':
  unittest.main()
```

to get the test working.